# set application to frontmost in applescript

Tags: applescript

I'm trying to find out what the frontmost application x is, run a script, then set x to the frontmost application using applescript.

```
    tell application "System Events"
set frontApp to displayed name of first process whose frontmost is true
set apptemp to frontApp
end tell
```

[code here]

```
tell application "System Events"
set frontmost of process whose name is apptemp to true
end tell
```

Although this code does not return any bugs it does not work.  I've also tried this code

```
tell application "System Events"
set apptemp to application "Google Chrome"
set frontmost of process "Google Chrome" to true
end tell
```

But again, although there are no bugs it will not work.

Also, someone please tell the admin to make it easier to display code.  I have the most difficult time displaying code on this website.  I have to indent four spaces for each line of code, that's insane.

Comment: Regarding the code indention from the help: *You can also select text and press CTRL+K to toggle indenting as code*.

Comment: They need to make that more clear on the webpage.

Answer (score 6):

A robust way to handle this is to use `path to frontmost application` as follows:

```applescript
# Save which application is frontmost (active),
# as an absolute, HFS-style path string pointing to the application bundle.
set frontmostAppPath to (path to frontmost application) as text

# Activate and work with another application.
activate application "Reminders"
delay 2

# Make the previously frontmost (active) application frontmost again.
activate application frontmostAppPath
```

Using the application's specific path ensures that the very same application is reactivated, irrespective of potential duplicates in different folders; also, this method is not affected by applications whose *process* name differs from the application name.
However, should there be *multiple instances* of the application running, it isn't necessarily the original instance that is reactivated.

Note: It's tempting to want to save and restore the object reference `frontmost application` *directly*, but that doesn't actually work: inexplicably, such a saved reference is treated the same as the *current* application (the one running the code).

Answer (score 3):

Even better than both other approaches is using the bundle identifier which is a unique key.

```
tell application "System Events"
    set frontAppID to bundle identifier of first process whose frontmost is true
end tell

-- Sample code... can be anything else
activate application "Finder"
delay 3
-- End of sample code

activate application id frontAppID
```

Comment: You could shorten to `id of application ((path to frontmost application) as text)`, but even then I don't see how that's better than using just the path, which is also unique. You mention _two_ approaches - what is the other one?

Comment: How do use bundle identifier in an if-clause? Something like "if frontAppID of bundle identifier of first process whose frontmost is "com.apple.safari" then..." doesn't work.

Comment: if (bundle identifier of first process whose frontmost is true is "com.apple.safari" ) then ...

Comment: Not unique.  Use `unix id` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Bundle & path fail when multiple instances are running.  Use `unix id` instead, e.g., https://StackOverflow.com/a/78130117/3008405